# Can someone explain what this line is doing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone help me understand what is happening on line to of this function

```
function getContainer(container, defaultContainer) {

    //this line below
    container = typeof container === 'function' ? container() : container;

    return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(container) || defaultContainer;
}
```

container is being assigned the result of typeof container, but if container is equal to a function, invoke that function.

I'm a bit head blagged. This code was pulled from the material ui docs for the react component Modal

Comment: You should look up ternary operator, that's what the `a ? b : c` construct is called (in many programming languages, not just Javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is saying the following:

`if` `container` is a function assign it to a variable called `container` and the function will be invoked, `else` set the variable `container` as the argument `container` passed to the `getContainer` function.

You could also write it like this, which maybe easier to read:

```
if (typeof container === 'function') {
   container = container();
} else {
   container = container;
}
```

In your example it is using the ternary operator which is another way of writing an `if`/`else` statement. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Thanks man, typeof was throwing my off completely and I didn't realise I  was looking at a ternary operator

Comment: @juicy89 just to throw in my two cents, you shouldn't be doing this. your function arguments should just be one datatype and you should use it how you expect to. its generally a bad code practice to call a function with different data types

Answer (score 3):

The equal would be:

```
if(typeof container === 'function')container= container();
else container = container;
```

which calls container if it is a function and stores the result in the variable named container. It it isn't it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First, know the basics and **the difference in the way we reference** the function/method in js.

Let's say there is a function named container

```
function container() {

    let name = 'Js';

    return name;
}

console.log(container()); //js as we got the value here

console.log(typeof(container())) // string as this time we have value which of string type

console.log(typeof(container)) // function as we are pointig to function
```

we got complete function structure in the console when we reference only function name  without  ()

```
  console.log(container);  
    ƒ container() {

        let name = 'Js';

        return name;
    }
```

To know what is  [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

So in your question, it checking what is passed and last thing to know is

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

i.e [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)